# Get HITID on Mturk

Tags: list, mechanicalturk

I would like to know how can I Get the HITID of my surveys of Mturk ? It's easy to see on TurkPrime, but on MTurk I can't seem to find it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The HITId is not easily accessible on the Requester website, which uses "batches" instead of HITs to organize the interface. If you visit the ["Manage HITs Individually" page](https://requester.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs), you will find a listing of HITs. The HITIds for each are not visible, but you can find them by either:

1. Doing an "inspect element" action from your browser's context menu on the iframe displaying the HIT. The HITId will be in the URL of the iframe's `src` attribute, or
2. Click on "Delete this HIT" (or just copy the link to that page). The HITId is part of the URL.

Another option, which requires that you created the HIT in the requester website (not on TurkPrime or anywhere else) and requires downloading a file, is to click the "Download CSV" for the appropriate batch. The HITId will be listed in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to [Manage HIT](https://requester.mturk.com/manage) and select the HIT you want to get her HITID. Press the results button and download the results CSV file. The first two columns in the CSV are HITId and HITTypeId.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by going here: https://requester.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs

Then hover over "Delete this HIT":

[image]

Right click and copy the URL. Analyze the URL and you'll see the HIT ID as a parameter.

The format will be something like:

```
https://requester.mturk.com/mturk/manageHIT?viewableEditPane=manageHIT_delete&HITId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

It's the value after `&HITId=`

Answer (score 0):

This past week, Mechanical Turk made finding the HITTypeId easier when you use the Requester UI. Here's how it works:

1. Visit http://requester.mturk.com and login
2. Click the Create tab
3. Click "New Batch with Existing Project"
4. Click on the "Project Name"
5. A pop up lightbox will appear. It used to show only "Layout ID" and "Layout Parameters" but it now also shows "HITTypeId"

To get the HITIds, the best approach is to download the CSV results which include the HIT IDs for your batch.

Hope that helps!